# arangodb Facet calculation / aggregation slow?

Tags: arangodb

I wonder why the following facet calculation takes so slow:

```
FOR q IN LRQ  
    COLLECT profile = q.LongRunningQuery.Profile INTO profiles 
RETURN { "Profile" : profile, "Count" : LENGTH(profiles)}
```

It takes about 30 seconds, although only 5.000 documents are in the db, and only 30 different facets are in the result.

The field LongRunningQuery.Profile is indexed with a hash index, and with a skiplist index.
(I also tried with different combinations of them).

Has anybody a hint for me what might go wrong? Is it possible that the queries do not benefit from the indexes? (the 5.000 records are about 1 GB of size, so I assume the hash index will not be used, maybe a fulltable scan instead?)

Interestingly, the following alternative only lasts 2 seconds:

```
FOR q IN SKIPLIST(LRQ, { "LongRunningQuery.Profile": [ [ '>',  ''  ] ] })[*].LongRunningQuery.Profile
    COLLECT profile = q INTO profiles
RETURN { "Profile" : profile, "Count" : LENGTH(profiles) }
```

But it still needs 2 seconds - for such a small amount of records. Here it looks like the skiplist index is used, but it is maybe not the perfect index variant.

---

**Update 2014-11-27:**

```
arangosh [_system]> stmt._query
    FOR q IN LRQ COLLECT profile = q.LongRunningQuery.Profile INTO profiles RETURN {
     "Profile" : profile, "Count" : LENGTH(profiles)}

arangosh [_system]> db.LRQ.ensureHashIndex("LongRunningQuery.Profile");
{
  "id" : "LRQ/296017913256",
  "type" : "hash",
  "unique" : false,
  "fields" : [
    "LongRunningQuery.Profile"
  ],
  "isNewlyCreated" : false,
  "error" : false,
  "code" : 200
}
```

The query took about 32 seconds and returned 31 short results.

Execution plan:

```
    {
        "plan": {
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "type": "SingletonNode",
                    "dependencies": [],
                    "id": 1,
                    "estimatedCost": 1,
                    "estimatedNrItems": 1
                },
                {
                    "type": "EnumerateCollectionNode",
                    "dependencies": [
                        1
                    ],
                    "id": 2,
                    "estimatedCost": 5311,
                    "estimatedNrItems": 5310,
                    "database": "_system",
                    "collection": "LRQ",
                    "outVariable": {
                        "id": 0,
                        "name": "q"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "CalculationNode",
                    "dependencies": [
                        2
                    ],
                    "id": 3,
                    "estimatedCost": 10621,
                    "estimatedNrItems": 5310,
                    "expression": {
                        "type": "attribute access",
                        "name": "Profile",
                        "subNodes": [
                            {
                                "type": "attribute access",
                                "name": "LongRunningQuery",
                                "subNodes": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "reference",
                                        "name": "q",
                                        "id": 0
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "outVariable": {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "3"
                    },
                    "canThrow": false
                },
                {
                    "type": "SortNode",
                    "dependencies": [
                        3
                    ],
                    "id": 4,
                    "estimatedCost": 56166.713176593075,
                    "estimatedNrItems": 5310,
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "inVariable": {
                                "id": 3,
                                "name": "3"
                            },
                            "ascending": true
                        }
                    ],
                    "stable": true
                },
                {
                    "type": "AggregateNode",
                    "dependencies": [
                        4
                    ],
                    "id": 5,
                    "estimatedCost": 61476.713176593075,
                    "estimatedNrItems": 5310,
                    "aggregates": [
                        {
                            "outVariable": {
                                "id": 1,
                                "name": "profile"
                            },
                            "inVariable": {
                                "id": 3,
                                "name": "3"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "outVariable": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "profiles"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "CalculationNode",
                    "dependencies": [
                        5
                    ],
                    "id": 6,
                    "estimatedCost": 66786.71317659307,
                    "estimatedNrItems": 5310,
                    "expression": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "subNodes": [
                            {
                                "type": "array element",
                                "name": "Profile",
                                "subNodes": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "reference",
                                        "name": "profile",
                                        "id": 1
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "array element",
                                "name": "Count",
                                "subNodes": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "function call",
                                        "name": "LENGTH",
                                        "subNodes": [
                                            {
                                                "type": "list",
                                                "subNodes": [
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "reference",
                                                        "name": "profiles",
                                                        "id": 2
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "outVariable": {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "4"
                    },
                    "canThrow": false
                },
                {
                    "type": "ReturnNode",
                    "dependencies": [
                        6
                    ],
                    "id": 7,
                    "estimatedCost": 72096.71317659307,
                    "estimatedNrItems": 5310,
                    "inVariable": {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "4"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "rules": [],
            "collections": [
                {
                    "name": "LRQ",
                    "type": "read"
                }
            ],
            "variables": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": "q"
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "profile"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "4"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "profiles"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "3"
                }
            ],
            "estimatedCost": 72096.71317659307,
            "estimatedNrItems": 5310
        },
        "warnings": []
    }
```

Update 2014-12-05:

Here are additional measures:
Understood, thanks. Here's the output:

Execution of 
AQL_EXECUTE('FOR q IN LRQ FILTER q.LongRunningQuery.Profile == "Admin" LIMIT 1 RETURN q.LongRunningQuery.Profile', {}, { profile : true }).profile
-->
{ 
  "initializing" : 0,
  "parsing" : 0,
  "optimizing ast" : 15.364980936050415,
  "instanciating plan" : 0,
  "optimizing plan" : 0,
  "executing" : 0
}

Execution of 
AQL_EXECUTE('FOR q IN LRQ COLLECT profile = q.LongRunningQuery.Profile INTO profiles RETURN { "Profile" : profile, "Count" : LENGTH(profiles)}', {}, { profile : true }).profile
-->
{
  "initializing" : 0,
  "parsing" : 0,
  "optimizing ast" : 0,
  "instanciating plan" : 0,
  "optimizing plan" : 0,
  "executing" : 77.88313102722168
}

### Update 19.12.2014:

Since 2.3.2 the execution plan for the query
arangosh [_system]> stmt2 = db._createStatement('FOR q IN LRQ  COLLECT profile  = q.LongRunningQuery.Profile INTO profiles RETURN { "Profile" : profile, "Count" : LENGTH(profiles)} ')

looks like this:

```
arangosh [_system]> stmt2.explain()
{
  "plan" : {
    "nodes" : [
      {
        "type" : "SingletonNode",
        "dependencies" : [ ],
        "id" : 1,
        "estimatedCost" : 1,
        "estimatedNrItems" : 1
      },
      {
        "type" : "IndexRangeNode",
        "dependencies" : [
          1
        ],
        "id" : 8,
        "estimatedCost" : 5311,
        "estimatedNrItems" : 5310,
        "database" : "_system",
        "collection" : "LRQ",
        "outVariable" : {
          "id" : 0,
          "name" : "q"
        },
        "ranges" : [
          [ ]
        ],
        "index" : {
          "type" : "skiplist",
          "id" : "530975525379",
          "unique" : false,
          "fields" : [
            "LongRunningQuery.Profile"
          ]
        },
        "reverse" : false
      },
      {
        "type" : "CalculationNode",
        "dependencies" : [
          8
        ],
        "id" : 3,
        "estimatedCost" : 10621,
        "estimatedNrItems" : 5310,
        "expression" : {
          "type" : "attribute access",
          "name" : "Profile",
          "subNodes" : [
            {
              "type" : "attribute access",
              "name" : "LongRunningQuery",
              "subNodes" : [
                {
                  "type" : "reference",
                  "name" : "q",
                  "id" : 0
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "outVariable" : {
          "id" : 3,
          "name" : "3"
        },
        "canThrow" : false
      },
      {
        "type" : "AggregateNode",
        "dependencies" : [
          3
        ],
        "id" : 5,
        "estimatedCost" : 15931,
        "estimatedNrItems" : 5310,
        "aggregates" : [
          {
            "outVariable" : {
              "id" : 1,
              "name" : "profile"
            },
            "inVariable" : {
              "id" : 3,
              "name" : "3"
            }
          }
        ],
        "outVariable" : {
          "id" : 2,
          "name" : "profiles"
        }
      },
      {
        "type" : "CalculationNode",
        "dependencies" : [
          5
        ],
        "id" : 6,
        "estimatedCost" : 21241,
        "estimatedNrItems" : 5310,
        "expression" : {
          "type" : "array",
          "subNodes" : [
            {
              "type" : "array element",
              "name" : "Profile",
              "subNodes" : [
                {
                  "type" : "reference",
                  "name" : "profile",
                  "id" : 1
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type" : "array element",
              "name" : "Count",
              "subNodes" : [
                {
                  "type" : "function call",
                  "name" : "LENGTH",
                  "subNodes" : [
                    {
                      "type" : "list",
                      "subNodes" : [
                        {
                          "type" : "reference",
                          "name" : "profiles",
                          "id" : 2
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "outVariable" : {
          "id" : 4,
          "name" : "4"
        },
        "canThrow" : false
      },
      {
        "type" : "ReturnNode",
        "dependencies" : [
          6
        ],
        "id" : 7,
        "estimatedCost" : 26551,
        "estimatedNrItems" : 5310,
        "inVariable" : {
          "id" : 4,
          "name" : "4"
        }
      }
    ],
    "rules" : [
      "use-index-for-sort"
    ],
    "collections" : [
      {
        "name" : "LRQ",
        "type" : "read"
      }
    ],
    "variables" : [
      {
        "id" : 0,
        "name" : "q"
      },
      {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "profile"
      },
      {
        "id" : 4,
        "name" : "4"
      },
      {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "profiles"
      },
      {
        "id" : 3,
        "name" : "3"
      }
    ],
    "estimatedCost" : 26551,
    "estimatedNrItems" : 5310
  },
  "warnings" : [ ],
  "stats" : {
    "rulesExecuted" : 25,
    "rulesSkipped" : 0,
    "plansCreated" : 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Can tell me which version of ArangoDB you are using? 2.2 or 2.3?

Comment: I suspect this is related to some extensive copying for the `COLLECT` operation. A bug has been reported for this here: https://github.com/triAGENS/ArangoDB/issues/1107

Comment: I am using 2.3 already.

Comment: But I remember this was also slow in 2.2

Comment: The strings within "profile" a few and short: in Total there are about 40 different Strings with a maximum length of 30 Charakters each. Would this fit to a memory-leak in the COLLECT?

Comment: I added some more details in the main description above

Answer (score 1):

hm, looking at the explain there is a sortnode, while your query doesn't provide a sort? 
the collect probably keeps the optimizer from employing your index (you would have an IndexRangeNode instead of a EnumerateCollectionNode then)

If you pass the options parameter of the query (4th parameter of db._query())
{  profile : true }
it will output the time used by the phases; can you re-run your query with that, and show us the reply?

Comment: I'd be happy to do so. Seems like I'm doing something wrong here, but what?

My call was:
c = db._query('FOR q IN LRQ COLLECT profile = q.LongRunningQuery.Profile INTO profiles RETURN { "Profile" : profile, "Count" : LENGTH(profiles)}', null, null, { profile: true});
c.elements()

... but in this case I do not get profiling information. In other queries, I got profiling information.

Any hints?

Comment: hm, ok need to take a different approach. Please run arangod with --console and execute the query like this: AQL_EXECUTE("FOR u IN _users RETURN u", {},  { profile : true }).profile

Comment: Understood, thanks. Here's the output:

Execution of 
AQL_EXECUTE('FOR q IN LRQ COLLECT profile = q.LongRunningQuery.Profile INTO profiles RETURN { "Profile" : profile, "Count" : LENGTH(profiles)}', {}, { profile : true }).profile
-->
{
  "initializing" : 0,
  "parsing" : 0,
  "optimizing ast" : 0,
  "instanciating plan" : 0,
  "optimizing plan" : 0,
  "executing" : 77.88313102722168
}

Comment: Another measure looks different:

Execution of 
AQL_EXECUTE('FOR q IN LRQ FILTER q.LongRunningQuery.Profile == "Admin" LIMIT 1 RETURN q.LongRunningQuery.Profile', {}, { profile : true }).profile
-->
{ 
  "initializing" : 0,
  "parsing" : 0,
  "optimizing ast" : 15.364980936050415,
  "instanciating plan" : 0,
  "optimizing plan" : 0,
  "executing" : 0
}

Comment: And in the meanwhile I use version 2.3.1 !

Comment: ok, now I got it. 2.3.2 will choose the index for the collect. The current devel branch already does it properly. It already gives me:  { 
        "type" : "IndexRangeNode", 
        "estimatedCost" : 5000, ....
        "index" : { 
          "type" : "skiplist", 
          "id" : "62193446495", 
          "unique" : false, 
          "fields" : [ 
            "LongRunningQuery.Profile" 
          ] 
        }, 
        "reverse" : false 
      } instead of the sortnode you got. Current plans are to release 2.3.2 early next week.

Comment: I just looked into this. Having a skiplist index on "LongRunningQuery.Profile" produced an execution plan with an IndexRangeNode for me, in versions 2.3.0, 2.3.1, the 2.3 and the devel branches. The IndexRangeNode means the index will be used to iterate over the documents in the collection. This also enables a removal of the SortNode. The SortNode is inserted automatically by the AQL engine because the COLLECT/AggregateNode needs sorted input. Do you remember how you managed to produce the plan without the IndexRangeNode? I cannot reproduce this in any version.

Comment: Hi all, short update:
1.) now the 2.3.2 was available, I installed it. But unfortunately the first tests of the "sick query" show no difference. Still 20 - 30 seconds runs ...
--> Next I will make a test with a completely new generated database, maybe this helps ...
2.) No, I don't know how this plan was produced. I only generated indexes, removed them, generated new and other ones - all that in different orders while trying to understand what happens. I did nothing else "actively" :-)

Comment: No, unfortunately it still is very, very slow. (We recreated the database content from scratch, but this did also not help).

Any further help for me?

Comment: Ahh, interesting. If I activate a skiplist index, it will be used (but still lasts a minute to answer). But if I only have a hash index, it will be ignored.
So, does this kind of query already need a skiplist (although no sorting statement is used)?
And why it still takes more than a minute to calculate 5000 records, no matter if an index can be used (according to the execution plan) or not? (tested in two different installations)

Comment: Here the new output of AQL_EXECUTE:

2014-12-15T11:28:58Z [5260] INFO ArangoDB (version 2.3.2 [win64]) is ready for b
usiness. Have fun!
ArangoDB JavaScript emergency console (ArangoDB 2.3.2 64bit -- ICU 52.1, V8 3.16
.14, OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014)
using pretty printing
arangod> AQL_EXECUTE('FOR q IN LRQ FILTER q.LongRunningQuery.Profile == "Admin"
LIMIT 1 RETURN q.LongRunningQuery.Profile', {}, { profile : true }).profile
{
  "initializing" : 0,
  "parsing" : 0,
  "optimizing ast" : 0.9772069454193115,
  "instanciating plan" : 0,
  "optimizing plan" : 0,
  "executing" : 0
}

Comment: And arangod> AQL_EXECUTE('FOR q IN LRQ COLLECT profile = q.LongRunningQuery.Profile
INTO profiles RETURN { "Profile" : profile, "Count" : LENGTH(profiles)}', {}, {
profile : true }).profile
{
  "initializing" : 0,
  "parsing" : 0,
  "optimizing ast" : 0,
  "instanciating plan" : 0,
  "optimizing plan" : 0,
  "executing" : 66.30042481422424
}

Comment: Indexes are arangosh [_system]> db.LRQ.getIndexes()
[
  {
    "id" : "LRQ/0",
    "type" : "primary",
    "unique" : true,
    "fields" : [
      "_key"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id" : "LRQ/296017913256",
    "type" : "hash",
    "unique" : false,
    "fields" : [
      "LongRunningQuery.Profile"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id" : "LRQ/530975525379",
    "type" : "skiplist",
    "unique" : false,
    "fields" : [
      "LongRunningQuery.Profile"
    ]
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

The `COLLECT` statement requires sorted input. Therefore, a `SORT` statement will be added to the execution plan automatically, even if the original query string does not contain an explicit `SORT` statement.

This is why a SortNode appeared in the plan. The SortNode will be optimized away if there is a skiplist index on the sort attribute (in this case `LongRunningQuery.Profile`). So adding a skiplist index on the attribute will speed it up as the (expensive) sort step can be spared.

If you have set up such index and run the query, it should be faster than when there is only a hash index. In fact, the original query should have ignored the hash index.

If you have set up the skiplist index and explain the query, you should also see that there is no SortNode anymore.

Starting with ArangoDB 2.4 (currently in devel stage), there is a more efficient syntax addition for just counting facets:

```
FOR q IN LRQ  
  COLLECT profile = q.LongRunningQuery.Profile WITH COUNT INTO numProfiles
  RETURN { "Profile" : profile, "Count" : numProfiles }
```

This should speed up the query even more.

Comment: Thanks, good to hear about further improvements in 2.4. And also thanks for your detailed explanation. My Problem is that I already have activated such a skiplist index, but either it will not be used or the performance still is very poor (a minute for 5000 records). Here's the index:
arangosh [_system]> db.LRQ.index("530975525379")
{
  "id" : "LRQ/530975525379",
  "type" : "skiplist",
  "unique" : false,
  "fields" : [
    "LongRunningQuery.Profile"
  ],
  "error" : false,
  "code" : 200
}

Comment: And the following statement works, but is it still worth 2 seconds (5.000 records, 30 results)?
FOR q IN SKIPLIST(LRQ, { "LongRunningQuery.Profile": [ [ '>',  ''  ] ] })[*].LongRunningQuery.Profile
    COLLECT profile = q 
RETURN { "Profile" : profile }

Comment: But I've detected that in the meanwhile the execution plan looks different than in former versions. Thus I've updated the details in   my explanation above.

Comment: Is it possible that especially the fact that those 5.000 records are *big* (> 1 GB together) makes the runtime slow, even with indexes?

Comment: The last execution plan you posted shows the index is used and there is no extra sort step. So the problem in query now must be the building of the group values variable (i.e. `profiles`). In the original version of the query, The entire documents will be copied into this variable, which will be expensive as the docs are > 1 GB as you mentioned. The `WITH COUNT INTO ...` extension in 2.4 should fix that. Until then, the `SKIPLIST()`-y version of the query probably doesn't copy that much and will thus be faster for now.

Comment: Anyway, I will look into how the amount of copying can be reduced for queries that will not benefit from the `WITH COUNT INTO ...` extension.

Comment: THANKS!!!! Now with 2.4 everything is fine. The indexes will be used, the nwe COUNT INTO .. does a good job, and the need to copy the big objects explains the rest. Great Job, thanks again.